# Understanding css height and margin

Tags: css

I am new to css and need your guidance. I have a an image background and 2 test lines needs to be placed in that.The top distance between text and image top border should be 50 px. Below to this text there is another text. The distance between these 2 text is 10px. And the distance between the second text(lower text) and the lower end of the image should be 40 px.
I have come up with the below code. Do I need to hardcode height for the first class to be 100px? If I do that the two text becomes too congested. Please let me know if the below code is correct

**HMTL**

```
<div class="header1">
    <div class="header2" >
        The first text goes here
    </div>
    <div class ="header3">
        The second small tesxt goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header1{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("1.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
}
.header2{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:42px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.header3{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height:40px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

Comment: use line height for text instead o fheight

Comment: requirement is line-height is NA

Comment: why u r repeating the same code font-family: Arial;
    color:#FFFFFF; many time just place these in header1

Comment: margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:40px; instead of writing the above lines u can do it in single line like margin : 10px 0 40px 170px ie top right bottom left

Comment: div is a block element no need to specify display block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to hardcode heights, or indeed use any heights here, if the content is more important than having the header exactly 100px tall.

Take a look at this fiddle, which uses the CSS below. I think this meets your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/2LetS/4/

```
body { color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; }

.header1 { 
    background: #ff0000; /* Replace this with your image. */
    padding: 50px 0 40px 170px;
}

.header2 { 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    font-size: 42px;
}
```

- 50px between top of header and first text
- 10px between first and second text
- 40px between second text and bottom of header

Note in the example I'm using padding on the .header1 element to define the space around the text, and margins to separate the text elements themselves. You'll also notice there's a lot less CSS code to achieve the same thing.

For your personal development, I think getting an idea of the **box model**, and what effects margin, padding, widths and heights have on block and inline elements will improve your knowledge immensely for the future.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel..Thanks for the sample. But it did not work with my requirement as the font for both the texts are different. First text font is 42 and second is 16. So it is creating a problem

Comment: Take a look at the updated fiddle in the post - the top text is 42px and the second is 16px. The font size shouldn't matter if you don't hardcode your DIV element heights.

Comment: Hi Daniel..Yes now it looks fine except for one thing. In the firebug layout the content area is shown as 1180x57. So the height is shown as 57. But I want as 50px. Any help?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand - which bit is the 'content area'?

Comment: The header1 is showing 57px and header2 is showing as 22px. Don't they be 50 and 40px. Please correct me if I am wrong. I got this from the firebug console Layout. I am not able to paste the screenshot here...

Comment: Ah, this may be the browser styles kicking in - different browsers apply different CSS rules to elements by default, unless you explicitly override them. Check this fiddle and see if it fixes your issue, and if so, I'll update my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/2LetS/5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37599/discussion-between-daniel-attfield-and-user1049057)

Answer (score 0):

You code is good, you juste need to add this line :

```
.header1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note : `.header3 { margin-top:10px; }` isn't required, you already fixed this margin on `.header2`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7Kh/)

Comment: But the gap between first line and image top end doesn't look like 50px and similarly for the second line and image end.How can I check this in firebug the "The first text goes here" and the image top border should be 50px. Similarly "The second small tesxt goes here" and image bottom end should be 40px.

Comment: Yes it is : http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7Kh/ You can check it in Firebug : go into `HTML` panel, search for your div and hover it, you'll see margins colored in yellow.

Comment: It looks bigger because the text element itself is 40px tall, which means there's a fair bit of space under the text created by that element. THEN you add the 40px margin, which makes the gap larger than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

According to standards.... For Headings & Sub Headings use H1, H2, H3 Heading tags & define separate styles in css

```
<div class="header1">
    <h1 class="header2" >
       The first text goes here
    </h1>
    <h3 class ="header3">
       The second small text goes here
    </h3>
</div>
```

1. There is no need to define div with class header1 as block as div is already a block level element.
2. Use % and em as unit of measurements for responsive design.
3. Always use fallback fonts for font-family property
4. Try to use shorthand notation for padding, margin, background, border etc.

   padding: top right bottom right;
   margin: top right bottom right;
   background: image_url color repeat-yes/no position;

Comment: Those tips are welcome, but did we talked about responsive design ?

Comment: he written clearly at top that he is newbie in css. So those tips will be helpful to know standards to write better css. As he is newbie he is using px for measurements. It better for him to CSS3 standards. Your opinion is welcome....